# LibGdx World Rendering on a wronge scale

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

Hi i currently have a problem in LibGdx, when i create an object in my world called world it's drawn not at the right scale, in this example I try to create a Box at 00 with the Size of the tiles but it is way to big.
Just to clarify I use BoxD2 just for Light not for Physics.

I create my world like this:

```
    world = new World(new Vector2(0.0f, 0.0f), false);
```

I create a Box with in this step ("this" is my player obj)

```
    BodyDef boxDef = new BodyDef();
    boxDef.type = BodyType.StaticBody;
    boxDef.position.set(this.getX(), this.getY());

    body = pState.world.createBody(boxDef);

    PolygonShape pShape = new PolygonShape();
    pShape.setAsBox( Data.TileSize , Data.TileSize );

    body.createFixture(pShape, 0.0f);
```

And it always get drawn by the DebugRenderer in the write possition but with double the Size if I change the Size the position is messed up.

The position is correct but it is not at the size it should be since `Data.TileSize` is the same as well the size of one Tile.

I'm sorry if this is a stupid question but I am a beginner and I am not a native English speaker so please excuse the language mistakes.
Yours Tifferan

Answer (score 0):

The reason it's double the size is that you're meant to pass in half the width/height into PolygonShape.setAsBox(...). Here's the JavaDoc for [setAsBox](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/PolygonShape.html#setAsBox-float-float-).

P.S. I always make this mistake :)

Comment: tanks a lot That was the problem

Comment: If that solved the problem it's better to accept the answer than just comment. Thanks.